# Error Updating data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I am unable to figure out the exact problem of the given code when i try to update.

```
protected void UpdateService(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        int ServiceId = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblServiceID")).Text);
        string ServiceName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtService")).Text;
        decimal Rate = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtRate")).Text);
        string ParentService = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlParentService")).SelectedItem.Text;
        string GrandParentService = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddlGrandParentService")).SelectedItem.Text;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "update Service set ServiceName=@ServiceName,Rate=@Rate,"+
        "ParentService=@ParentService,GrandParentService=@GrandParentService "+
        "where ServiceId = @ServiceId;" +
         "select ServiceId,GrandParentService,ParentService,ServiceName,Rate from Service";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ServiceName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Rate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParentService", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ParentService;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@GrandParentService", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GrandParentService;


        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }



private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);                    //Error "Must declare the scalar variable "@ServiceId".
        return dt;
    }
```

I am getting an error message "Must declare the scalar variable "@ServiceId" at the time of update. "ServiceId" is the primary key for the table.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a `@ServiceId` in your `SqlCommand` but you never add it as a parameter with `Parameters.Add()` method.

Comment: ServiceId is my primary key.

Comment: But like Soner said, you still need to pass the ServiceId value, otherwise how will your SQL command know what row to update if you're not passing anything in your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2):

You're specifying a `@ServiceId` parameter in your query but never declaring or adding one in your command. You need to specify this when performing an update, or leave off the where clause when inserting a new row.

```
cmd.CommandText = "update Service set ServiceName=@ServiceName,Rate=@Rate,"+
    "ParentService=@ParentService,GrandParentService=@GrandParentService "+
    "where ServiceId = @ServiceId;" +
     "select ServiceId,GrandParentService,ParentService,ServiceName,Rate from Service";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ServiceName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Rate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParentService", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ParentService;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GrandParentService", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GrandParentService;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1; //Some Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query has a parameter called `@ServiceId`:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update Service set ServiceName=@ServiceName,Rate=@Rate,"+
"ParentService=@ParentService,GrandParentService=@GrandParentService "+
"where ServiceId = @ServiceId;" +  // <--- right here
 "select ServiceId,GrandParentService,ParentService,ServiceName,Rate from Service";
```

But you never add such a parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ServiceName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Rate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParentService", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ParentService;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GrandParentService", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = GrandParentService;
```

To the SQL code, `@ServiceId` is a variable that's never declared or assigned a value, hence the error.  You need to add a parameter for it:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ServiceId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like ServiceId is not being given a value even though @ServiceId is in your WHERE clause..

You are adding a parameter for ServiceName but not ServiceId

Comment: ServiceId is my primary key. How do i update please elaborate.

Comment: You are performing an UPDATE so this assumes you know the Service Id

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ServiceId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ServiceId ;
```